# using group by and maximum

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a post table and postcontent table.

Each time post is edited,an entry is added to postcontent table .

On each such time a filed called version will be incremented by 1
In the postcontent table.

How can I fetch   PostId, from post able and [Description] from to postcontent table 
Where version for each post is maximum
Ie  group by  post id
ie i am expecting one raw for each post such that it is the 'maximum of version' for the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    p.[PostID],
    pc.[Description]
FROM
    [Post] AS p
INNER JOIN
    [PostContent] AS pc
    on p.PostID = pc.PostID 
WHERE
    pc.[Version] = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM PostContent WHERE PostID = p.PostID)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select P.PostID,
       PC.[Description]
from Post as P
inner join 
  (
    select PostID,
           [Description],
           row_number() over(partition by PostID order by [Version] desc) as rn
    from PostContent
  ) as PC
  on P.PostID = PC.PostID
where PC.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think u have the `PostId` in `PostContent` table as a foreign key and you want to retrive all the `postId` with their Heighest version .

```
select max(version),PostId from PostContent groupby PostId
```